# Required textbox in javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery

I have this code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#<%= chkSpecialIntegration.ClientID %>").click(function () {
            if (this.checked) {
                document.getElementById('<%=ddlTypeSpecialIntegration.ClientID %>').style.visibility = 'visible'; }
  });
    });
```

When this is checked then a textbox is no longer required.  How can I do this?

Comment: I donÄ't understand. Can you clarify?

Comment: Updated with what I think the question is.

Comment: Just a thought, but if you post the actual jQuery/JavaScript as seen by the browser the question might make more sense. Of course it would help if you could post the corresponding (x)html, and clearly state your question.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is make ddlTypeSpecialIntegrationvisible when chkSpecialIntegration is checked, you can just do:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#<%= chkSpecialIntegration.ClientID %>").toggle(function() {
            $("#<%= ddlTypeSpecialIntegration.ClientID %>").show();
  }, function() {
            $("#<%= ddlTypeSpecialIntegration.ClientID %>").hide();
});
    });
```

Comment: but how can i make a textbox required = "true "

Comment: Okay, then I'm not understanding the question after all.  Can you show the markup for the textbox in question?  What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways that an html textbox can be forced to be required.  You should implement both.

The first is to validate the data prior to form submission.  You can accomplish this in javascript by hooking into the onsubmit event.  An example is at http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_form_validation.asp

Inside that method you will need to test if your checkbox is selected or not.  If it isn't, then see if they typed something in your textbox.

The second is to validate it server side after form submission.  For this you could simply provide some validation code in your button's server side onclick method.

I say to implement both because you will want to provide immediate feedback when something is required client side and you want to enforce it server side in case javascript is turned off.

Of course, if JS is turned off then they will probably never see the textbox to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need JS for that?

Isn't something like this enough?

```
<input<% if some_condition %> required="required"<% endif %> name="field" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Give id for textbox like

```
<%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FirstName, new { @tabindex = "1", maxlength = "50" ,id="Name"})%>
```

$(document).ready(function () {

```
    $("#<%= chkSpecialIntegration.ClientID %>").click(function () {
        if (this.checked) {
            document.getElementById('<%=ddlTypeSpecialIntegration.ClientID %>').style.visibility = 'visible';
```

$("#Name").hide;

}
  });
    });